# How to use DatetimeIndex as an index in Pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, indexing, datetimeindex

I have a dataframe called region and the an array `y` is `DatetimeIndex` type like that:

```
print(y)
DatetimeIndex(['2016-01-01 00:30:00', '2016-01-01 01:30:00',
               '2016-01-01 02:00:00', '2016-01-01 03:00:00'])
```

But the problem, *I do not know how I should use `y` as index in `region`*. I tried to make it simpler with:

```
region["2016-01-01 00:30:00"]  # this line gives me an error KeyError: '2016-01-01 00:30:00'
```

I do not know why, however, this datetime is included in the index of region.

**I am also looking for explanation for these results:**

```
region["2016-01-01 00"]    # this works with me and print the result correctly
region["2016-01-01 00:30"]    # this does not work and gives me an error
region["2016-01-01 00:30:00"]    # this does not work and gives me an error
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with `.loc`

```
region.loc[y]
```